# block all directorys but one file?

Tags: php, apache

i'm using Apache and i have the following folders in the root folder

```
/images/
/pages/
/storage/
```

how can i block access to any files in those folders, also blocking access to the directorys above but allow access to only the `index.html` file that is located in the root folder?

how is this done in the config file AND `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **.htaccess** file in the root folder and specify the following content inside it:

```
<Directory /path/to/diretcory>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
<Directory>
```

**Or**, create a file for each directory containing this content:

```
<Files *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple.
Create a `.htaccess` file in the root directory with this content:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "index.html">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This will deny access for everybody. If, though, the requested file is "index.html" then it'll allow access.